# SVN Commit Error

Tags: svn

I'm trying to allow multiple users to access/commit to my repo and I'm running into permission issues (as expected).  I followed the steps in the SVN book and I'm still getting this error:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Can't create directory '/usr/home/peter/svn/db/transactions/16-1.txn': Permission denied
```

I've set the SUID bit on the db directory, wrote a wrapper script which sets the umask to 002 then executes the 'svn' command and set group permissions to rwx on all directories in svn/

My Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 002
/usr/local/bin/svn "$@"
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever user/group your svn server process runs as needs to have rwx permissions on everything in the /usr/home/peter/svn directory.  So if your svn server runs as the svn user/svn group, you need to run:

```
chgrp -R svn /usr/home/peter/svn; chmod -R g+rwx /usr/home/peter/svn
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory /usr/home/peter/svn/db is not writable by the user calling the script.  You have the SUID bit set on the directory, but is it writable by a group that the calling user is a member of, or world writable?

Comment: Actually, /usr/home/peter/svn/db is writable by the users group, however the directories within are not.  Should I manually change all directories and files to be group rwx?

Comment: There are only a few directories that need to be writable: dav, dv, and locks.  And you'll only need the dav directory to be writable if you plan on using the apache module for hosting content.