# cannot commit svn with dav on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

So there are several similar questions on serverfault ... but the solution is still eluding me.

I am running subversion on Ubuntu 9.04 .. through apache2.2.x    ....

I get

```
Commit failed (details follow):

Can't make directory '/home/kirb/svn/dav/activities.d': Permission denied
```

when I attempt to commit.

It is definitely a permissions issue... but how to fix it is still eluding me.

My repository is in /home/kirb/svn.

[SVN Commit Error](https://serverfault.com/questions/61573/svn-commit-error) says to chgrp .. but I don't seem to be able to. All the apache DAV stuff seems to be working though. I can access my repository just fine through a browser.

Apologies if i am missing something simple here.

Thanks in advance,
   Kirb

additional edit:  I am not able to sudo chgrp on the directory at all

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /home/kirb/svn; chmod -R g+rwx /home/kirb/svn
[sudo] password for kirb:
chmod: changing permissions of `/home/kirb/svn': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `/home/kirb/svn/format': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `/home/kirb/svn/conf': Operation not permitted
chmod: cannot read directory `/home/kirb/svn/conf': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of `/home/kirb/svn/locks': Operation not permitted
chmod: cannot read directory `/home/kirb/svn/locks': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of `/home/kirb/svn/db': Operation not permitted
chmod: cannot read directory `/home/kirb/svn/db': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of `/home/kirb/svn/README.txt': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `/home/kirb/svn/hooks': Operation not permitted
chmod: cannot read directory `/home/kirb/svn/hooks': Permission denied
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more info.  What URI are you using to checkin/out? When you say "it's working though a browser", do you mean read-only access? Who is Apache running as? +any other detail you can see...

Comment: i'd like not to share my subversion uri... but yes myurl.com/svn allows me to login and read the files in the repository.

Comment: i can check out using tortoise on my local machine (not my server) ... i just cannot commit

Comment: In my case, I had to create the dav folder before it would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the svn files to be in the `www-data` group, *and* make them all group-writable.  For example, if the repository is `/var/svn`, then

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/svn
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/svn
```

should do it.  (Although, come to think of it, you've probably already figured this out...)

Comment: thank you for answering and taking the time. hopefully this helps future people.

Answer (score 0):

Since you accessing the folder with apache, probably the user `www-data` needs to be able to read/write the folder.

Comment: i have ran ...

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/kirb/svn/*
  481  sudo chmod -R 770 /home/kirb/svn/*`

Comment: Did it work? In your original post you did not run chmod with sudo, that's why it failed.

Comment: running it with sudo still gave me permissions errors.  havent gotten it to work yet.